# RabbitMQ - Create primary and secondary consumer

Tags: rabbitmq

Is it possible in RabbitMQ to set one consumer (i.e. Android App) as primary, but to send the message to a sencond consumer (i.e. server) when the first consumer is not acknowledging the message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When one consumer is not ACKing the messages they get re-queued (after some timeout or when connection terminates etc) and then they are distributed to other consumer(s) in round robin manner.

Also what you may be interested in are [consumer priorities](https://www.rabbitmq.com/consumer-priority.html).

> Consumer priorities allow you to ensure that high priority consumers
>   receive messages while they are active, with messages only going to
>   lower priority consumers when the high priority consumers block.